Flutter Golden Toolkit. Mock native function
I am trying to test my Page with Golden_Toolkit package in Flutter
group('AudioPlayer Test', (){
    late MockAudioPlayer mockAudioPlayer;
    setUp(() {
      mockAudioPlayer = MockAudioPlayer();
    });

    //TODO cant mock audio native method
    testGoldens('admin collection page', (tester) async {
      when(mockAudioPlayer.play(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => 1);
      final builder = DeviceBuilder()
        ..addScenario(
            widget: const MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: AdminCollectionPage()));
      await tester.pumpDeviceBuilder(builder);
      await screenMatchesGolden(tester, 'admin_collection_page');
    });
  });

This page uses AudioPlayer and path_provider packages, i can mock path_provider functions with
TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
      .setMockMethodCallHandler(
          const MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/path_provider'),
          (MethodCall methodCall) async {
    return '.';
  });

But i still cant mock AudioPlayer class with method above.
Logs below:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ 
The following MissingPluginException was thrown running a test (but after the test had completed):
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method create on channel xyz.luan/audioplayers)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioplayersPlatform.create (package:audioplayers_platform_interface/src/audioplayers_platform.dart:18:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioPlayer._create (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:175:7)
<asynchronous suspension>

